# Using smart pointers as arguments of Qt standard functions

Tags: c++, qt, stl, smart-pointers

Everything is in the title : i was wondering if it was possible to use a smart pointer as a function parameter instead of a raw pointer?

For example i wanted to use a `QsharedPointer<QStringListModel>` instead of a `QStringListModel*` as a parameter for the function QListView::setModel.

This is not only about the Qt framework but also the STL in general.
Unfortunately Google was unable to help me this time..

Comment: No, you cannot use smart pointers as parameters for functions that expect raw pointers, unless there is a conversion operator for it.

Comment: You have to convert it to a raw pointer with get() although that will probably defeat your reason for using a smart pointer in the first place. My advice is to just use the parent / child relationship to handle ownership. With `QObject` when a parent is destroyed it frees all of its children. Make sure you set the parent on your model.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` also have a `get()` method to retrieve the raw pointer. Again remember to make sure that you don't use the raw pointer after the life of the object ends.

Answer (score 1):

If function takes raw pointer as argument then no, it's not possible. However, you can get raw pointer from smart pointer using `get()` method and pass it as argument.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the `setModel` function has an overload accepting a `QsharedPointer<QStringListModel>`, you need to supply the raw pointer stored in your shared pointer. You can use `shared_ptr_variable.data()` to do that.